How to trigger nav2 docking on turtlebot3 simulation with ROS2 Humble?
I'm trying to run nav2_docking with Turtlebot3 Simulation in Gazebo...
This is the steps which I've done so far:
I've installed navigation2, opennav_docking, turtlebot3, turtlebot3_simulation and turtlebot3_msgs's humble branches in my new workspace and I've built it with colcon build --symlink-install. Then I run the below commands in different terminals:
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py
ros2 run opennav_docking opennav_docking
This is the output which I got when I run opennav_docking:
[INFO] [1723443584.776447305] [docking_server]: 
    docking_server lifecycle node launched. 
    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1723443584.776578052] [docking_server]: Creating docking_server

My question is how should I send to robot to docking?

If you have set up your dock database, either declaring it in your nav2 parameter file, or in its own database file, you can run this command in a separate window,
ros2 action send_goal /dock_robot nav2_msgs/action/DockRobot "{dock_id: <YOUR_DOCK_ID_HERE>}" --feedback
You can either supply it with a dock id from the database, or fill out the pose parameters manually in the command. What you are doing is calling the docking action server, emulating an action client which you can implement into a separate control node.
For an example of an action client node, This is from the turtlebot4 tutorials, which uses This library to send and check various nav2 action servers.

Is there any tutorial on how to setting up database etc...

The nav2 documentation has a good tutorial, link here!. The only other issue I could see is that the docking server requires that the dock pose be published if using an external dock detection system, ex: AprilTags or other visual recognition. As I have only used this package for physical robots, there may not be a baked in solution in turtlebot3. Look for the /detected_dock_pose topic when running the simulation.

Finally, I was able to send the robot to dock in the simulation. I've used opennav_docking::SimpleChargingDock as in tutorial. But the robot can't dock successfully even if I've tried at least 50 times. Do you think is it because the parameters?

When it tries to dock, what error message does it give before aborting?
This Link goes into what those errors mean. When I first worked with this, I was getting many 903 (failing to stage), 904 (can't detect dock with external detection), and 906 (failed to charge, if battery state is used). You can also look at the feedback stage to see what the server is currently doing when it fails.

Now I can successfully dock forward, but I want to dock backwards. When I change the value to dock_backwards: true, It still can't dock backward... What can be the reason?

And I was wondering If I can give orientation to staging point?

I am not familiar with docking backwards, but I would ensure that whatever method of dock pose detection you are using does not rely on robot orientation (ex. camera on only the front of robot).
You can also manually give a pose to navigate to, instead of relying on the built-on nav-to-starting-pose, if initial pose is an issue.
